# Angular 6 Dynamic Views with Auxiliary Routes and clean URL's

Tags: angular, url, routes, angular6

In my Angular 6 project, I have some components that have a sidebar, and some of them don't. I tried to do this with auxiliary routes and it worked, but the URL's are ugly as ...!

--

What I do:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
},
{
    path: 'search',
    component: SearchComponent
},
{
    path: 'sidebar',
    outlet: 'sidebar',
    component: SidebarComponent
}
```

which gives me them possible URL's

```
https://localhost:4200/login - (login without sidebar)

https://localhost:4200/login(sidebar:sidebar) - (login with sidebar)

https://localhost:4200/search - (search without sidebar)

https://localhost:4200/search(sidebar:sidebar) - (search with sidebar)
```

--

The desired result is just to have the URL's /login and /search, but the search with the sidebar and the login without the sidebar. **How can I do this?**

Are auxiliary routes the right way to do this? Or is there another way to do this right?

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue in Github that asked the same question: [Auxiliary routes with Clean URL](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24819) and the answer given was to provide a custom implementation of Angular's [UrlSerializer](https://angular.io/api/router/UrlSerializer).

Try this:

custom-url-serializer.ts

```
    import { DefaultUrlSerializer, UrlTree, UrlSerializer } from '@angular/router';

    export class CustomUrlSerializer implements UrlSerializer {
        private defaultUrlSerializer: DefaultUrlSerializer = new DefaultUrlSerializer();

        parse(url: string): UrlTree {
            // Manipulate the url string here as per requirement
            let newUrl = url.split('(')[0];
            let urlTree: UrlTree = this.defaultUrlSerializer.parse(newUrl);
            return urlTree;
        }

        serialize(tree: UrlTree): string {
            return this.defaultUrlSerializer.serialize(tree);
        }
    }
```

app.module.ts:

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { UrlSerializer } from '@angular/router';
    import { CustomUrlSerializer } from './custom-url-serializer';

    @NgModule({
      // other properties
      providers: [
        {
          provide: UrlSerializer,
          useClass: CustomUrlSerializer
        }
      ]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

Keep in mind that Angular doesn't know about your auxiliary route anymore when parsing the URL, because we removed it. Therefore, you should handle it by some other means, like using a service to know which auxiliary route you are on or making use of queryParams etc...